# showing div as popup in asp.net MVC 4 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view in my asp.net MVC 4 application like this:

```
   <form class="qty-add" action="#" method="POST">
        <label>Qty:</label>
        <div class="inp-controller">
            <a href="#" class="min">-</a>
            <input type="text" name="qty" readonly="readonly" />
            <a href="#" class="plus">+</a>
        </div>
        <button id="btnAddToCart" type="submit" >+ ADD TO CART</button>
    </form>
```

and a div which i want to show as popup:

```
<div id="dvContents" style="display: none">

<form id="product-options">
    <div class="header">
        <div>Please select the options for your product.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="formfield jqtransform clearfix">
            <select>
                <option>Topping</option>
                <option>Vanilla Ice</option>
                <option>Strawbery</option>
                <option>Apple Pie</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="formfield jqtransform clearfix">
            <select>
                <option>Cake Size</option>
                <option>Size 1</option>
                <option>Size 2</option>
                <option>Size 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-orange-2ln"><span>Continue Shopping</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-red-2ln"><span>Checkout</span></a>
    </div>
</form>
 </div>
```

and js like this:

```
 $("form.qty-add button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

                var skinName = $(this).data('skin');
        var css3Effects = $(this).data('css3effect');
        var effect = $(this).data('effect') || "fade";
        var href = $(this).data('src');
        var width = $(this).data('width') || null;
        var height = $(this).data('height') || null;

    });
```

I want to show divcontents as popup when user clicks submit button and post the form to action method. How can I do this ?

Comment: cant you pass a parameter on user click like '1' and check on dom load on the page you want to popup div using ViewBag or I misunderstood you

Comment: @brykneval I just need to hide dvContents on page load but show dvContents as popup when add to cart button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to style the popup div.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #dvContents
    {
            display: none; /*hide the div initialy*/
        width: 250px; /*set the width of the div*/
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black; /*define a styling border*/
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px;
        position: absolute; /*postition the div in center of screen*/
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -75px 0 0 -125px;
    }
</style>
```

Second, write these two functions to show and hide the div, repectively:

```
    var showDiv = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dvContents").show();
    }

    var hideDiv = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dvContents").hide();
    }

    $("#btnAddToCart").click(showDiv); //Assign the show function to the click event
```

This will show the popup in center of screen when the user presses the submit, + ADD TO CART, button. I hope it helps. Good luck